# I have built a shopping cart using React. Why isn't my cart working? By working I mean why isn't the count in the cart increasing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopping-cart

I have a built a shopping cart using React. The cart is not displaying the total of items in the cart after 1. That is 1 is the maximum count it can count. I would like it to count to more than 1 items. Here is the `Cart` Component:

**Cart.js**

```jsx
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import formatCurrency from '../util';


    export default class Cart extends Component {
    render() {
        const { cartItems } = this.props;
        //this part is not displaying the number of items in the cart
        return (
            <div>
                {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <div className="cart cart-header">Cart is empty</div>
        ) : (
          <div className="cart cart-header">
            You have {cartItems.length} in the cart{" "}
          </div>
        )}

                <div>
                <div className="cart">
                    <ul className="cart-items">
                        {cartItems.map(item => (
                            <li key={item._id}>
                                <div>
                                     <img src={item.image} alt={cartItems.title}></img>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>{item.title}</div>
                                    <div className="right">
                                    {formatCurrency(item.price)} * {item.count}
                                        <button onClick={ () => this.props.removeFromCart(item)}>         Remove</button>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ) )}
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            
           
        );
    }
}
```

**App.js**

*I have included the state too*

```jsx
    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: data.products,
      cartItems: [],
      size:"",
      sort:"",
    };
  }

    //this part is not working

    addToCart = (product) => {
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    let alreadyInCart = false;
    cartItems.forEach((item) => {
      if (item._id === product._id) {
        item.count++;
        alreadyInCart = true;
      }
    });
    if (!alreadyInCart) {
      cartItems.push({...product, count: 1 });
    }
    this.setState({cartItems});
    };
```

Here is link to code on Github: [Link To Github](https://github.com/GithakaMbui/Shopping-Cart)

Comment: What happens when you try to add a product to the cart?

Comment: Use map instead of forEach, and return item after increasing count

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
addToCart = (product) => {
  const { cartItems } = this.state;
  // find whether the product is there in the cartItems
  const isProductPresent = cartItems.some(item => item.id === product.id);
  if(isProductPresent){
    const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map(item => {
      if(item.id === product.id){
        return { ...item, count: ++item.count}
      }
      return item;
    })
    this.setState({cartItems: updatedCartItems});
  }
  else {
    this.setState({cartItems: [...cartItems, {...product, count: 1}] });
  }
  };
```

Comment: this is doing nothing different than the original code. The count in the cart is not increasing beyond 1

Comment: Then you should add the shape of the object within the cartItem as well .

Comment: Its not clear from your questions what you mean by `count` - Do you mean the individual item`s count or the `cartItems.length` ?

Comment: @Augustin i downloaded your code and ran in my local and looks like there is typo :-) . There is no `_id` property in your item . It is just `id` . change your code to this `if (item.id === product.id) {` . It should work fine :-)

Comment: Also while inspecting your code i can see three products with the id `van3` . so you need to pass some unique value to `id` else if you try to add all the 6 items to the cart only 4 will get added because there is only 4 unique Id's . Try adding all 6 items to cart .

Comment: your solution worked pretty fine. There was a typo in the code.